# How to count number of unique fields in a csv file with uneven number of columns in each row

Tags: bash, csv, unix, uniq

I am having a csv file containing an extract of variables for files in a specific directory. Thus the number of columns vary per row, like this:

```
filename1,variable1,variable2,variable3,variable4
filename2,variable1,variable2,variable5
filename3,variable1,variable5,variable6,variable7,variable8
```

(trailing commas have been removed)

The command:

```
awk -F ',' "{print NF}" < input.csv
```

Do not really do the trick, since it just displays the number of columns for the "largest" row in the file for all rows.

It would be great if I could get the number of variables of each row, and more importantly, get the count of unique fields in the whole file.

The ideal output for the first request would be something like:

```
filename1   4
filename2   3
filename3   5
```

The ideal output for second request (number of unique fields in the whole file):

```
8
```

Any great ideas on how to approach this?

Thanks,

Best wishes, Birgitte

Comment: paste expected output pls.

Comment: The ideal output for the first request would be something like:
filename1 .  4
filename2 .  3
filename3 .  5

The second request (number of unique fields in the whole file):
8

Comment: don't put them in comment, edit your question, add them in code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your two requirements can be done in one shot:

```
awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]}{print $1, NF-1}
         END{print "total unique vars:"length(a)}' file.csv
```

With your example data as input, we got:

```
filename1 4
filename2 3
filename3 5
total unique vars:8
```

If you want to divide them into two cmds:

```
awk -F, '{print $1, NF-1}' file.csv
```

And

```
awk -F, '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)a[$i]}END{print length(a)}' file.csv
```

Comment: Thank you! this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

This may be slower than a single `awk` script, but it's always nice to have an alternative:

#### Number of unique variables in the whole file

```
$ cut -d, -f2- file | tr , \\n | sort -u | wc -l
8
```

#### Number of variables per line

```
$ paste \
   <(cut -d, -f1 file) \
   <(grep -no , file | uniq -c | tr -s ' ' \\t | cut -f2)
filename1   4
filename2   3
filename3   5
```

Comment: Thank for you for the alternative! :)